# Accessing more than default parameters (to, from, subject, reply_to) for rails mail interceptor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method within a mailer called `notification_mailer.rb`:

```
def reminder_email
    @community = @reminder.community
    subject = "random subject text"
    mail(from: address_for(support), reply_to: address_for(support), to: to_address, subject: subject)
end
```

I am trying to use a mail interceptor `check_mail_settings.rb`:

```
class CheckMailSettings
  def self.delivering_email(mail)   
    if @community.status = "mute"
      mail.perform_deliveries = false
    end
  end
end
ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(CheckMailSettings)
```

But this interceptor does not actually have access to the `@community` variable.  I have tried passing it in the mail call in `notification_mailer.rb` like so

```
mail(community: @community, from: address_for(support).....)
```

and accessing it within the interceptor `check_mail_settings.rb` like this

```
mail.community
```

but that does not work either.

Is there any way I can get access to this `@community` variable within the interceptor `check_mail_settings.rb` or will I need to do any conditionals involving `@community` within the `notification_mailer.rb` beforehand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while i don't think that what you are doing there really makes sense, it is possible.

in the interceptor you get an instance of `Mail::Message`. it has access to whatever you pass into the `mail` call.

so in the example you provided it would be

```
mail[:community].value
```